Why can't I substitute in a variable into 'git for-each-ref --exclude=...'?
I have the branches abc, def and develop. This works fine:
$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --exclude=refs/heads/{abc,develop} refs/heads/
def

Why can't I substitute abc,develop for a variable?
$ BR=abc,develop; echo $BR
abc,develop
$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --exclude=refs/heads/{$BR} refs/heads/
abc
def
develop

Substituting other parts of the expression works just fine:
$ FOREACH=for-each-ref; FORM="%(refname:short)"
$ git $FOREACH --format="$FORM" --exclude=refs/heads/{abc,develop} refs/heads/
def

Context: I'm trying to list remote branches without a local equivalent, by using git for-each-ref on heads, using tr to transform it into a comma-separated list, and then using git for-each-ref on remotes. I found a ready-made solution here, but I still want to understand why mine didn't work.

First, Bash expands --exclude refs/heads/{abc,develop} into --exclude refs/heads/abc refs/heads/develop. I'm sure this is not what you want. Most probably you want --exclude refs/heads/abc --exclude refs/heads/develop. You can do that replacing a space with =:
--exclude=refs/heads/{abc,develop}

Second, Bash doesn't do double expansion:
$ echo git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --exclude=refs/heads/{$BR} refs/heads/
git for-each-ref --format=%(refname:short) --exclude=refs/heads/{abc,develop} refs/heads/

If you want to expand {} further after expanding $BR ask Bash to do the second round:
$ eval echo git for-each-ref '--format="%(refname:short)"' --exclude=refs/heads/{$BR} refs/heads/
git for-each-ref --format=%(refname:short) --exclude=refs/heads/abc --exclude=refs/heads/develop refs/heads/

So the answer for your question is
eval git for-each-ref '--format="%(refname:short)"' --exclude=refs/heads/{$BR} refs/heads/


Thanks. I've fixed OP to use =. It's always dangerous to type examples manually into SO instead of copy-pasting exactly what you're testing...
